# How to change background color of a page in Asp.net through color picker

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I'm developing a page in which I've given users an interactivity to change the background color of a page by clicking particular button. I am trying to find out through various sites but they are giving the information about how to change the background color of the text box or grid view. it is a bit like customization tool which you find in various sites like orkut and face book.

Answer (score 1):

in the css/style

```
body
{
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

But since it seems like you want to change the color on the fly then either in a javascript or code behind, change the class of the body to one that has background-color applied.

eg. for the code behind, make sure to set the  with a runat="server" and id
and then in code behind:

```
bodyId.Attributes["class"] = "test";
```

in css:

```
.test
{
  background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Note that this will happen after a postback, while in the sites you mentioned it probably uses javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to modify the DOM on the fly, which would be perfect for your situation. Here's a quick sample using the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method. Once you make that change, you can store the value in a cookie or some other mechanism and use it next time the page is loaded.

```
//assumes MyButtonId is the id of the button the user clicks
$('#MyButtonId').click(function () {
  //set the background-color of the body element to green
  $('body').css('background-color', '#00F') 
});
```